# NullPointerException while testing app

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, nullpointerexception

I've got a problem while testing my app, class "DateToday" exactly, here's part of that class:

```
public DateToday(){
    monthName();
    dayName();
    dayNumber();
    yearNumber();
}

public int yearNumber(){
    year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    return year;
}
```

And here's my test class:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 21)
public class DateTodayTest {

private DateToday mDateToday;

@Test
public void checkYear() {
    assertEquals(mDateToday.yearNumber(), 2016);
}
```

Why I am still having `NullPointerException` at `checkYear()` method and the test is failed? It may be a stupid issue but I am blind with that...

Comment: You must initialize `mDateToday`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems mDateToday is not initialized, you should use the constructor:

```
private DateToday mDateToday =  new DateToday ();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was it!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create new instance of `DateToday` class before calling `assertEquals()` method like: `mDateToday = new DateToday();`